# Mytop помощь и расшифровка

Tags: mysql

Помогите пожалуйста расшифровать mytop. Что означает красные Ratio и Ratio now? И как решить проблему?
[image: mytop]

```
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 528      |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 12088840 |
| Qcache_hits             | 814089   |
| Qcache_inserts          | 191740   |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0        |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 2515     |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 3171     |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 6995     |
+-------------------------+----------+
```

Скажите, нужно ли кеширование query-cache-size включать?

Comment: Почему-то не могу найти документацию по этим параметрам в интернете.

Comment: Ratio is the percent of queries that are served from the query cache since the server started. Ratio now is the percent of queries served from the query cache since the last mytop refresh.

Comment: The key efficiency tells us the percent of queries that are using a key in the query. When doing any kind of SQL statement one should use a key unless it is a statement that is not often run. The reason for this is that queries without keys take longer to run but at the same time the more keys a database uses the larger a database will be because the key information has to be stored. So if a query is not run often and does not cause a load on the server due to the lack of a key in the query then you can probably get away without having a key in the query.

Comment: Если не можете перевести то: у вас не расставлены правильно индексы; у вас жирные запросы, которые не умещаются в кэш

Comment: Я сейчас приложу ещё 1 скрин. Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно ли вообще кеширование включать или нет.

Comment: После отключения кеша Radio пропали.